# Cambiar Precio con CSV en Prestashop

Tags: prestashop

Estoy tratando de cambiar el precio de los productos por medio de un archivo CSV en Prestashop 1.6 pero en el select que muestra los campos que puedo indicar de que columna se trata no me muestra alguna que sea para el Precio final ó Precio Base.

He intentado cambiar el precio seleccionando: Precio Unitario, Precio con IVA y  Precio sin IVA.

Adjunto imagen de las opciones que tengo con Prestashop.

[image: opciones]

Answer (score 0):

Tienes que poner el **precio unitario sin impuestos (Price tax excluded)** al cual se le aplica la **regla de impuestos (Tax Rule)** para calcular el precio final (que no es un campo que tu escribas, sino que es un campo calculado, por conveniencia).

Answer (score -1):

Solución: Utilizar versión de PHP 5.6 ya que las mayores (7) no permite estos cambios masivos con CSV.

Comment: Si se permite importar con CSV. Lo que has escrito no tiene un argumento que lo sustente y no lo has ofrecido. 

No solamente se permite CSV, sino que el equipo de Prestashop ahora (en 2022) también permite importar XLS, XLSX, y ODT.